# Trying to update a database with javascript/PHP doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm trying to update a database using javascript and PHP, this is my `index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="descriptioninput">
    <input type="number" id="budgetin">
    <input type="number" id="budgetout">
    <button type="button" onclick="addToDB()">Add to database</button>

    <script>
        function addToDB()
        {
            var descriptioninput = document.getElementById('descriptioninput').value;
            var budgetin = document.getElementById('budgetin').value;
            var budgetout = document.getElementById('budgetout').value;

            $.ajax ( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'addtodb.php',
                data:{descriptioninput:descriptioninput, budgetin:budgetin, budgetout:budgetout},
                success:function (data) {
                    // Completed successfully
                    alert('success!');
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my `addtodb.php` code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "budgetdb";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn === TRUE)
{
$descriptioninput = $_GET['descriptioninput'];
$budgetin = $_GET['budgetin'];
$budgetout = $_GET['budgetout'];

$query = "INSERT INTO budget (description, budgetin, budgetout) VALUES ('$descriptioninput', '$budgetin', '$budgetout')";

$conn->query($query);

$conn->close();
}

?>
```

But it appears as if my PHP script doesn't run. No changes appear in my database. I've tried to do warning() in the PHP file and alert it it using.done(function(text)), but nothing is displayed.

Comment: Yeah it seems like it didn't go inside if condition. First see what comes inside $conn when db connected successfully.

Comment: can u use developer console or firebug (on firefox) or something like that to see what is happening? And also test your server side code first.

Comment: $conn !== true, $conn == true - that's the problem. mysqli_connect does not return true.

Comment: First write echo inside if to confirm is condition meets.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are doing the ajax request using `POST` method in js but you are trying to get the variables using the `GET` method in PHP. Switch it to `GET` and it will work.

Be aware of [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). You can prevent it either by using prepared statements or escaping the string as:

```
$descriptioninput = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['descriptioninput']);
```

Also, the first `if` condition is not valid. You just need to do it like `if ($conn)` instead of `if ($conn === TRUE)`

Comment: Tried doing that, but nothing happens in the database. I even tried writing the url manually in chrome. I also changed the type to GET now.

Comment: It works now,  something was wrong with the SQL syntax it appears, after I removed the () before VALUES, it worked. I'll have a look at it

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sql syntax.. depends on what you are trying to save in db.. use the `real_escape_string` to assure there are no wrong chars sent for db

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam I tried to run the SQL query directly in PhpMyAdmin, which failed. Then I removed `(`description`, `budgetin`, `budgetout`)` and it ran successfully in PhpMyAdmin, so I did the same in my PHP file which made it work.

Comment: Indeed, perhaps description is a reserved keyword and should be avoided for column names?

Comment: I don't think so.. but you may try using it like **INSERT INTO \`budget\` (\`description\`, \`budgetin\`, \`budgetout\`) VALUES ('$descriptioninput', '$budgetin', '$budgetout')**

Comment: Have you checked echo $query?

Answer (score 1):

Change ajax type to GET

```
$.ajax ( {
type: 'GET',
url: 'addtodb.php',
data:{descriptioninput:descriptioninput, budgetin:budgetin, budgetout:budgetout},
success:function (data) {
// Completed successfully
alert('success!');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but i believe description may be a reserved keyword in mySQL. try encapsing it

```
INSERT INTO budget (`description`, `budgetin`, `budgetout`) VALUES ('$descriptioninput', '$budgetin', '$budgetout')
```

Answer (score 0):

its a little messy with your mix between ajax and JS. Try using this getHTTP function for regular JS.

```js
function httpGet(theUrl){
 //FETCH Data From Server
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl , false );
 xmlhttp.send();   
 return xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

then just build your url as +addtodb.php?param1="+param1value+"&param2="+param2value

Comment: appologize. I am without sleep i was miss thinking ajax as jquery. I am not verry knowledgeable in ajax but the above is how i accomplish calling a PHP file.